# Cast shadows to SCNNodes in ARKit

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to attach a `Spotlight` to the ARCamera:

```
fileprivate lazy var spotLight: SCNLight = {
    let spotLight = SCNLight()
    spotLight.type = .spot
    spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 0
    spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 45
    spotLight.castsShadow = true
    return spotLight
}()

sceneView.pointOfView?.light = spotLight
```

But there's a problem. Light works well, but there is no shadow. What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

put a plane underneath, set it uncheck all rgba values for it.
Go to the light source node, set cast shadows, set it to deferred.

Answer (score 1):

Move the spotlight somewhere else (I.e don’t use the exact same position as the point of view otherwise the shadow will be behind what you see).